# MacOS type of aliases to file

Tags: symlink, macos

I know how to create symlinks in linux (Raspberry Pi OS), but i try find a way to create MacOS type of aliases which point to file or folder.

Comment: Could you explain how macOS aliases are different?

Answer (score 0):

It's the same as in linux: just use `ln -s`, e.g.

```
ln -s ~/Documents ~/Docs
```